# Accented and other non-ASCII characters do not display on web pages

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I want some help, my website is not showing some characters like ë,-,  etc etc..

i have tryed this method to get them

```
function UTFeer($v) {

    //reject overly long 2 byte sequences, as well as characters above U+10000 and replace with ?
    $v = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]'.'|[\x00-\x7F][\x80-\xBF]+'. '|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*'. '|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})'. '|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/S', '?', $v);

    //reject overly long 3 byte sequences and UTF-16 surrogates and replace with ?
    $v = preg_replace('/\xE0[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]'. '|\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]/S','?', $v );

    return $v;
}
```

The database i had is from wordpress, right now i am not using wordpress any more but a customs system to get the data from db.
Please can some one help, about how to show all characters in the website .. 
Thank you

EDIT: Now i am using, this code and it seems that works, but is this code "heavy " for the website?

```
function normalize_special_characters( $str )
{
    # Quotes cleanup
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("`")), "'", $str );        # `
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("´")), "'", $str );        # ´
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("„")), ",", $str );        # „
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("`")), "'", $str );        # `
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("´")), "'", $str );        # ´
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("“")), "\"", $str );       # “
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("”")), "\"", $str );       # ”
    $str = ereg_replace( chr(ord("´")), "'", $str );        # ´

$unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'&Euml;', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                            'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                            'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'&euml;', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                            'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$str = strtr( $str, $unwanted_array );

# Bullets, dashes, and trademarks
$str = ereg_replace( chr(149), "&#8226;", $str );    # bullet •
$str = ereg_replace( chr(150), "&ndash;", $str );    # en dash
$str = ereg_replace( chr(151), "&mdash;", $str );    # em dash
$str = ereg_replace( chr(153), "&#8482;", $str );    # trademark
$str = ereg_replace( chr(169), "&copy;", $str );    # copyright mark
$str = ereg_replace( chr(174), "&reg;", $str );        # registration mark

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: set the correct encoding for your db, for your db connection, in the http header in your meta tags. and finally make sure your browser is detecting the correct encoding

Comment: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` keyword here is php mysql utf8

Comment: Where did you get the code you quote, and who told you it would be appropriate for your problem? According to the comments, it is intended to remove _illegal_ and _unwanted_ UTF-8 sequences. It should do nothing for data that are already well-formed (and stays inside the BMP).

Comment: where should i paste mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); ?

Comment: @Meo Before you query the database for data, but after you've connected to it.

Comment: now i have a problem , if i press enter for a new row, it don't show that i have a new row. any solution ?

Comment: @Meo, there are no mentions of rows or keypresses at all in your question so far. Perhaps ask a new question if you have a new unrelated problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your data might be getting saved using the wrong character encoding.  For example, the database might be storing text as Latin-1, but it is not converting user input to Latin-1 before storing it (MySQL can't make the distinction because Latin-1 is a single-byte character set, so whatever it gets *could* be valid).

By the time the application pulls data back out of the database for display, there's no way of knowing how the characters are actually encoded.  Usually, this is combined with naïvely declaring the UTF-8 character encoding in the `content-type` header, which results in what you might call "WTF-8 encoding".

If you have filesystem access to the MySQL server, add the following to `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Once you make this change, you will need to restart the `mysqld` service on your server.

You can verify this worked by connecting to the MySQL server manually and issuing the following command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` LIKE 'character_set%' OR `Variable_name` LIKE `collation_%';
```

You should see something that looks like this:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci            |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

---

You are not quite done, though; this only sets the default charset/collation for any future-created data.  The existing data are not converted.

Fixing the existing data is not a particularly easy task, since you might have different rows in each table that were saved using different character encodings.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish it, though.  One method that might work here is to convert each text column into a `blob`, and then convert it back to a `text` (or `varchar`, etc.; convert it back to the type it was before you made it a `blob`), which will force MySQL to try to fix the character encoding:

```
ALTER TABLE `(table name)` MODIFY `(column name)` BLOB;
ALTER TABLE `(table name)` MODIFY `(column name)` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

See [this article](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL) for more information.

Comment: thnx for the nice answer, i see that the table is : character set utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci, at the database the text is like i want it to be, but when it is showed in web, the new rows are missing, idk how is called, but when i press a enter , in database is showed that i have preset enter and there is a new row where the pharagraph should start, but in my website it dont show the new row, this is strange, any solution? Best Regards

Comment: Hey @Meo.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.  This might be good material for a new question, since it sounds like a slightly different problem (all text disappears instead of specific entities not rendering), and we'll want to have a more in-depth look at the code that takes the user input and saves it in the database.

Comment: Can you also confirm that not only does the table have the correct charset/collation, but do the varchar/text columns as well?

Comment: I also updated the answer with new information, including noting that the `mysqld` service should be restarted after changing `my.cnf`, and adding a query you can use to verify that all variables are set properly.